# If string arrays are null terminated in C, why are arrays of other data types not null terminated?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Strings, or arrays of characters in C must be null terminated to know where they end. Why does the same rule not apply to arrays of other types?
eg. How does the computer know where an array of integers ends? Is there a difference in how arrays of integers/floats/doubles are represented in memory?

Comment: A C string and an "array of characters" are not the same thing. An array of characters need not be 0 terminated.

Comment: `Why does the same rule not apply to arrays of other types?` - it does. Some libraries need null/zero/some extra character delimetered data. From top of my head, ex. [getopt_long](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) uses an array terminated by `{0,0,0,0}`. It just happens that "a string" is defined by the C standard and the C standard library supports them.

Comment: @KamilCuk why even go as far as third-party libraries? Already `argv` in `main` is null-pointer-terminated :)

Comment: "other data types" can contain multiple zeros which are legal members of these types. So zero can't be a valid end-of-array marker.

Comment: That's a good example - the `argc` with `argv` may be an example of both methods together - you have the count in `argc` and still `argv` is null terminated. It's just a convention. It is used what is best for the use case.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays of characters do not have to be nul-terminated.

```
char foo[3]="foo"; //not nul-terminated
char bar[]={'b','a','r'}; //not nul-terminated
```

It's just that string literals are nul-terminated arrays, and that C makes it really easy to make nul-terminated arrays by using string literals as initializers:

```
 char baz[]="baz"; //nul-terminated because "baz" is
```

Why C does so is a choice the designer(s) made because [using a terminator seemed more convenient to them than maintaining character counts](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) next the character array.

But nothing in C forces this preference on you.

Comment: _string literal_ and _string_ are similar, yet different C  things.  An answer for a _string_ and _array of character_  question is more complicated with _string literal_ .

Answer (score 2):

A string in C is a sequence of `char` that is null terminated.  It's a special case of a `char` array.

You can have a `char` array that is *not* null terminated.  For example:

```
char x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

Arrays in general are represented as a contiguous sequence of the base type in memory.  The language itself doesn't keep track of how big an array is, you're expected to do that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: because that’s how C language is defined.

Longer answer: C strings are by itself nothing special. They’re a block of memory that contains bytes, just like any other block. But by defining a convention of terminating the string by 0 all functions can agree on ways to handle the strings.

They could have been done in a way that forces you to handle the length separately and always provide the pointer and length to every function. That is cumbersome so it’s better to just use the terminator. It’s also slower in cases like concatenation since first the ending location has to be looked up.

As for why it isn’t used with other types, it sometimes is. And the reason is the same: it was agreed upon as a convention and in the same way as strings. We don’t know how many values there are so we have a sentinel value in the end. It may be null, 0, or some other value. But we can also not do it and provide the number of elements separately.

It’s also often impossible and/or unnecessary to use a sentinel value, for example if we need the whole datatype or know the size of the data. For example, if we have an RGB image how will we define an end value? We need all the values the bytes can have to define the colors so we can’t have a sentinel. We also don’t need one since we know the size of the image.

As for the computer, it doesn’t know anything about the data. It can only handle bytes and words and whatever it’s built to handle. Strings are much higher level and handled entirely in the used language’s library. The processor just moves data around based on what you tell it to do. And for example PC BIOS uses $ as the terminator character when printing strings, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

You usually pass the length of the array along with the pointer. Nothing "knows" the length of anything.

Memory is memory. An array of bytes could have 0x42 0x41 0x44 0x00 in it, which happens to be the string for "BAD" But it could just as well be an integer representing "1145127936" or a float representing "773.0625"